# Suppose that {S1 , S2 } is a partition of a set S and x ∈ S. Which of the following are true?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, solution-verification

***Suppose that {S1 , S2} is a partition of a set S and x ∈ S. Which of the following are true?***

(a) If we know that x ∉ S1, then x must belong to S2.

(b) It’s possible that x ∉ S1 and x ∉ S2.

(c) Either x ∉ S1 or x ∉ S2.

(d) Either x ∈ S1 or x ∈ S2.

(e) It’s possible that x ∈ S1 and x ∈ S2.

This should be a fairly straightforward problem. To my mind, the only true solution is (a). However, the answer key states that (a), (c), and (d) are all true. It is my understanding that in math, a disjunction means "either P or Q or both P and Q."

So if (c) is true, then either x ∉ S1, or x ∉ S2, or x ∉ S1 and x ∉ S2. However, since the set {S1, S2} is a partition of S, and x ∈ S; x must belong to either S1 or S2, meaning the statement 'x ∉ S1 and x ∉ S2' is necessarily false by the definition of a partition. Hence, (c) must be false.

If (d) is true, then either x ∈ S1, or x ∈ S2, or x ∈ S1 and x ∈ S2. However, since a partition must be pairwise disjoint, 'x ∈ S1 and x ∈ S2' cannot be a true statement, so (d) must be false.

In my view, (a) is the only true statement; however, as I said, the answer key disagrees. Is my reasoning flawed? Am I misunderstanding the meaning of a disjunction?

Comment: "It is my understanding that in math, a disjunction means "either P or Q or both P and Q."" YES; see [Logical or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction).

Answer (score 2):

You might be slightly misunderstanding what a disjunction is... Let's take the example of (d):

> If (d) is true, then either x ∈ S1, or x ∈ S2, or x ∈ S1 and x ∈ S2.

Correct. But what 'or' means here is that *any one* of these statements being true is enough for the whole thing to be true. So...

-- if x ∈ S1, then the statement "Either x ∈ S1 or x ∈ S2." is correct.

-- if x ∈ S2, then the statement "Either x ∈ S1 or x ∈ S2." is correct.

-- if x ∈ S1 *and* x ∈ S2, then the statement "Either x ∈ S1 or x ∈ S2." is correct.

You are right when you say that the last statement can never be true, but it doesn't need to be. One of the first two cases will always hold, so that is enough for (d) to hold true.

(Sorry if that was confusing! Feel free to ask for clarification)

Comment: Thanks for this - looking back over the truth tables for the disjunction I see what you mean. Would it be fair to say this: 

Since  x ∈ S1 or x ∈ S2, but not both, (c) is true, since only one of the cases must hold. Otherwise a disjunction and a conjunction would be the same!! 



Weird that I wasn't seeing this last night...

Comment: Yep, that seems about right!